# HVAC automatic damper in zoned system

Tags: hvac

We have a 4 ton Carrier gas pack for our 1996 sq ft house.  A 2 zone system was installed when the unit was installed in 2015.  It has 2 thermostats and automatic dampers.  We have only had great results.  We are selling the home and the buyer's home inspector felt it was not working correctly because both thermostats control the unit (duh!).  They are concerned the dampers are not working correctly.  My question is if one zone is calling air, will some air flow still come out of the vents of the zone that is not calling air?  We do not have a problem with temperature control and feel it is working well.  I know that our unit is more than is needed for our ranch style home.  I am pretty sure there is a bypass damper as well.  Thoughts?

Comment: It sounds like the home inspector isn't familiar with zoned HVAC systems. It's on the buyer to have a HVAC contractor come out and test/verify that the system works properly. What would you do if the home inspector said he thought the heat out of the vents wasn't hot enough? Same thing, have someone who specializes in that come out and take a look.

Answer (score 1):

## 1 It sounds like it was installed according to standard engineering practices.

## 2 This type of installation is usual and customary practice by today's standards.

## 3 Sounds like the home inspector is out of his depth.

## 4 Have the original installed write a letter to the above effect.  That should do it.

### 1 These type of dampers are fairly tight.  They are gasketed.  You should see very little air movement in the area not calling.